# Seek advice from SEOs

Tags: seo, meta

I have read that Google no more uses meta tags to rank your website.
[لوله بازکنی دهکده المپیک](https://loolebazkoni.com/portfolio/%D9%84%D9%88%D9%84%D9%87-%D8%A8%D8%A7%D8%B2%DA%A9%D9%86%DB%8C-%D8%AA%D8%AE%D9%84%DB%8C%D9%87-%DA%86%D8%A7%D9%87-%D8%AF%D9%87%DA%A9%D8%AF%D9%87-%D8%A7%D9%84%D9%85%D9%BE%DB%8C%DA%A9/)

So what are the ways otherwise if I want to increase traffic or optimize my website for search engines so that more customer would get attracted to my website. we are running e-commerce business which is confined to a not very large area.
[لوله بازکنی غرب تهران](https://loolebazkoni.com/%D9%84%D9%88%D9%84%D9%87-%D8%A8%D8%A7%D8%B2%DA%A9%D9%86%DB%8C-%D8%BA%D8%B1%D8%A8-%D8%AA%D9%87%D8%B1%D8%A7%D9%86/)

Its only 5-6 months we have launched our website. Can I get any tips so that I can optimize my website for searching.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about SEO, not programming.

Answer (score 2):

You could register your website on the Google Webmaster tool :
https://www.google.com/webmasters/tools/home?hl=en

Not only you'll find a few tips about their SEO, but it will warn you if the Google crawler had problems while visiting your website, which could be the reason for your website to be ranked poorly.

Answer (score 1):

That is true about Meta tags - not relevant now.

There is no simple recipe to increase PageRank and search engines position.

There are huge amount of guides on web that can help. Professional companies offering positioning for payment. And also not every positioning practice is also "fair" and legal.

But for the general, I would say to answer your question:

- keep your web-code clean, and if possible meeting the W3C validators requirements: http://validator.w3.org/
- keep good-quality content
- thing that increasing your web-position is the fact that your page is linked on on other pages in positive and good-quality context. Try to achieve that (with to